# Date order is not chronological in ggplot2

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a graph that depicts insect visitation to a flower over time by insect order, however, the dates are not in order when depicted in the graph, despite them being sorted in order in the CSV. For some reason 1-May-20 is at the beginning when it's supposed to be near the middle. How do I fix this?

```
aadata %>%
group_by(`Flower.Species`, `Insect.Order`, Date) %>%
summarize(number = n()) -> date_counts_nopatch

ggplot(date_counts_nopatch, aes(Date, number, color = Insect.Order, group = Insect.Order)) + 
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(na.rm=TRUE) + 
    labs(x = "Date", y = "Number of visits", color = "Insect Order") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, colour = 'black'))
```

The image below is what it pops up as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M75na.png)

Comment: Convert your `Date` column to the `Date` class, otherwise it's just a string. Something like `aadata$Date = lubridate::dmy(aadata$Date)`. You can then use `?scale_x_date` if you want to customize formatting of the axis.